# Valgrind - how to run on many binaries

Tags: valgrind

How to run `valgrind` on many libraries?

I try to define `custom_target` in CMakeLists.txt and I try to define `COMMAND` as:

```
valgrind bin1 bin2
```

and valgrind runs only first binary.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind can only exercise one executable at a time.

You could do something like

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes script bin1 bin2
```

where `script` would be a shell script that loops over its arguments and executes them.

The disadvantage of this is that Valgrind will also be executing the shell, which will make things slower and generate more noise.